# How to link .NET 2.0 f/w environment for vs2003

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

vs2003 runs under 1.1 framework.Now install 2.0 framework.Now how can i link .NET 2.0 libraries such that VS2003 has intellisence of 2.0 libraries.How can i do this?? Is it possible if yes how can i do this

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use a Visual Studio version targeted at .NET 2.0 development (meaning either VS 2005 or VS 2008).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you can't do that. VS2003 will never know anything about .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is impossible. You cannot use .NET 2.0+ assemblies in .NET 1.x apps.